# How to perform color tone adjustments and write a look-up table?

Tags: python, opencv

I have to perform color tone correction on an image based on this graph:
[image]

The original image is the black dotted line and the blue and red channels need to be modified as the the graph suggests.

> Specify the intensity values in the color channels on the original curve ( black dashed line ) that need to be modified (create an array with the horizontal axis points 0, 50, …,250).

> Then, create the arrays with the new points on the Y-axis for each color channel. Make a Look-Up Table to store the interpolated values ( `np.interp()` ), so that you get a mapping from the original values to the modified values for each intensity level.

> Use the Look-Up Table to map the pixel values in the original image to the output image for the respective color channels and merge the modified channels to get the final output.

I wrote this, but am unsure as how to write the look-up table.

```
import cv2
import numpy

image = cv2.imread("my path", 1)

blueChannel = [0, 80, 150, 190, 220, 250] # i approxitamed the values in the graph
redChannel = [0, 25, 40, 75, 150, 250]
original = [50*i for i in range(0, 6)]

modifiedBlue = numpy.interp([i for i in range(0, 251)], original, blueChannel)
modifiedRed = numpy.interp([i for i in range(0, 251)], original, redChannel)

# lookUpTable = some code i dont know

finalImage = cv2.LUT(image, lookUpTable)
```

My understanding is that each pixel is an array of RBG channels and to perform the tone adjustment I only need to modify blue and red channels while leaving green channel undisturbed. But how do I write such a look-up table?

Comment: The green would simply be a straight line from bottom left to top right. See np.linspace for sequence of increasing numbers. Or same as original

Comment: @fmw42 and how do I go about writing that look-up table that `cv2.LUT()` needs?

Comment: Convert your blue, green and red color lists into 1D images. Then merge the 3 channels into a BGR color 1D image. That will be the LUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do that in Python OpenCV. Rather than make lists for each channel, select a few equally spaced columns and get the B,G,R values from your curves on the graph.

The following does not use your graphs, but simply selects a few random colors. But the concept is the same.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# make gray 3 channels
gray = cv2.merge([gray,gray,gray])

# define colors
color1 = (255,0,0)
color2 = (255,128,128)
color3 = (0,92,0)
color4 = (128,192,255)
color5 = (0,164,255)
color6 = (122,167,141)
color7 = (0,255,0)
color8 = (0,0,255)

# create 8x1 colors array
array8 = np.array([[color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6, color7, color8]], dtype=np.uint8)

# interpolate nearest neighbor to have 256x1 pixel image of 8 colors in blocks of 32
lut = cv2.resize(array8, (256,1), 0, 0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

# apply lut
result = cv2.LUT(gray, lut)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_gray.png', gray)
cv2.imwrite('lena_gray_colorized.png', result)

# display result
cv2.imshow('RESULT', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Gray image:

[image]

Colorized gray image using LUT:

[image]

Comment: You may want to interpolate the resize using bilinear for smoother color variations.

Comment: I had a noisy image to which I applied a medianFilter before and wat thinking about using the color correction on the smoothed out image. Is it better the other way around?

Comment: I think it is OK to do the filtering on the grayscale noisy image first. I would also suggest you use bilinear interpolation on the LUT

Answer (score 2):

Here is the other way to do it by creating 1D images for each channel from your curves in Python OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# make gray 3 channels
gray = cv2.merge([gray,gray,gray])

# define channel curves as images
redArray = np.array([[0, 20, 40, 75, 150, 250]], dtype=np.uint8)
greenArray = np.array([[0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]], dtype=np.uint8)
blueArray = np.array([[0, 80, 150, 190, 220, 250]], dtype=np.uint8)

# create BGR image
bgr = cv2.merge([blueArray, greenArray, redArray])

# interpolate nearest neighbor to have 256x1 pixel image of 8 colors in blocks of 32
lut = cv2.resize(bgr, (256,1), 0, 0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

# apply lut
result = cv2.LUT(gray, lut)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_gray.png', gray)
cv2.imwrite('lena_gray_colorized2.png', result)

# display result
cv2.imshow('RESULT', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Gray image:

[image]

LUT colored gray image:

[image]

Comment: You may want to interpolate the resize using bilinear for smoother color variations